# "Endereçar" com sentido de "lidar com"

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês, verbos, sinônimos, termos-em-inglês

Em inglês o verbo **address** pode ter o sentido de **deal with** (**lidar com**), como afirma o [Dicionário de Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/address):

> address: verb [T] (DEAL WITH)
> to give attention to or deal with a matter or problem:
>
> - The issue of funding has yet to be addressed.
> - They are guilty of a cowardly failure to address the problem.

De tanto ver esse uso de **address** no inglês, acabei interiorizando esse sentido e me peguei escrevendo algo como:

- *Podemos usar esse método para **endereçar** o seguinte problema.*

No entanto, acabei pensando melhor e fui procurar um sinônimo para **endereçar**. Nessa procura percebi que sentidos como **resolver**, **lidar com**, **solucionar** ou **enfrentar** não constam como um dos significados possíveis para o verbo **endereçar**, pelo menos não nos dicionários [Michaelis](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/endere%C3%A7ar/) e [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/endere%C3%A7ar).

Isso é evidência suficiente para afirmar que **endereçar** não pode ser usado como sinônimo de **lidar com** em português?

*Obs.:* Talvez um contraexemplo seria a aparição de **sobrepujar** como sinônimo de **endereçar** no [sinonimos.com](https://www.sinonimos.com.br/enderecar/).

Comment: Outra alternativa podia ser **abordar**, que tem o "a" (ad) como *address*.

Comment: Na verdade, no português, o cognato direto de *address* até é *adereçar* (ambos do latim vulgar _*addirectiare_), mas também não tem o sentido que pretendes.

Comment: Acho que você mesmo respondeu a pergunta quando consultou dois dicionários.

Comment: endereçar é address so para correio. to address an issue: abordar ou lidar com um assunto ou questão. É considerado um falso amigo de primeira.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como o Centaurus comenta, você já (quase) respondeu sua própria pergunta ao consultar os dicionários — consultei outros seis com o mesmo resultado nulo.

Isso não constitui prova absoluta que "endereçar" não pode ser utilizado com esse sentido ("lidar com"), mas é uma evidência forte e mostra que certamente não é usual: portanto você não seria compreendido, com exceção daqueles que fizessem a conexão com o inglês.

Comment: Eu tinha a esperança de que alguém encontrasse algum contraexemplo que mostrasse **endereçar** com sentido de **lidar com**, mas, como você mesmo disse, mais outros 6 dicionários com resultado nulo já são uma forte evidência. Obrigado!

Comment: This is the kind of thing that really bothers me about all these sites on SE. Endereçar is to address mail or letters to someone. to address an issue is abordar uma questão. Se isso fosse uma prova de tradução, seria um erro enorme.

Comment: Concordo, @Lambie, seria um erro, mas o OP sequer cometeu de fato esse erro (e, se tivesse cometido, estamos aqui para ajudar), mas sim percebeu que não parecia funcionar e pediu confirmação.