# Qual seria o termo, em português, mais próximo do verbo address em Inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês, verbos, termos-em-inglês

Achei uma pergunta onde o postador tem o mesmo problema que o meu: ["Endereçar" com sentido de "lidar com"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8964/endere%c3%a7ar-com-sentido-de-lidar-com)

Internalizamos o conceito de *address* do Inglês, mas eu não consigo achar um termo que seja bom para substituí-lo na fala em português.

O significado que eu procuro é o de "pensar sobre algo e começar a lidar com isso".
Se encaixaria na seguinte situação:

*-* Olá, você viu que abriram um chamado para um problema?

*-* Sim, depois que eu terminar o que estou fazendo vou *address* o chamado.

Comment: Me ocupar do chamado, tratar do chamado

Answer (score 4):

to address a problem or an issue
Merriam Webster:

b
: to deal with : TREAT
… intrigued by the chance to **address important issues** …
—I. L. Horowitz

**tratar (d)o problema.

Priberam:

14. Ter como assunto (ex.: o romance trata (d)a falta de comunicação nas relações humanas).    The novel **addresses** the lack of communication in human relationships.

"tratar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2023, https://dicionario.priberam.org/tratar.